# Using OpenCV in ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv

*NOTE: It isn't my machine, so I cannot upgrade it to Ubuntu 18, and I think the problem is unrelated to the ubuntu's version...*

I'm trying to use OpenCV in a Ubuntu 15.04, I was able to use it in a windows machine normally and had put the configuration on `qtCreator` so it could recognize the OpenCV.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\OpenCV-QT\install\include"
LIBS += -L"C:\OpenCV-QT\install\x86\mingw\bin" \
    libopencv_core320 \
    libopencv_highgui320 \
    libopencv_videoio320 \
    libopencv_imgcodecs320 \
    libopencv_imgproc320 \
    libopencv_features2d320 \
    libopencv_calib3d320
```

I have tried to put the config both in `/home/myuser` and `/`, but apparently it didn't work.
What should I do the configure the path just like in windows?

Comment: All questions about EOL releases are off-topic on this site, unless you are asking a question related to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic (*specifically the what to avoid section*)

Comment: I guess you didn't even read the question before saying i'm asking for support, but OK, I've removed the version from the tittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be happening because `qt` is not finding the libraries with the path you informed. When I had to install `opencv` those files were in "`/usr/local/lib`", try using this path for the `.so` and "`/usr/local/include/opencv`" for the `.hpp`.

Comment: It took me some time because i had to recompile it but with those directories it worked fine this time, thanks.